# Compiling python program via pyinstaller for windows FixTk,Tkinter,PyQt5,PySide not found

Tags: python, pyinstaller

This is out put while compiling FixTk,Tkinter,PyQt5,PySide not found how can i fix it??? i can import FixTk,Tkinter,PyQt5,PySide in interpreter. 
I m compiling under win xp and i have also tried on win 10 both are 32 bits

```
3525 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
4146 INFO: Looking for import hooks ...
4146 INFO: Processing hook   hook-distutils.py
4146 INFO: Processing hook   hook-xml.py
4226 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PIL.py
4226 INFO: Excluded import 'FixTk' not found
4226 INFO: Excluded import 'Tkinter' not found
4226 INFO: Excluded import 'PyQt5' not found
4226 INFO: Excluded import 'PySide' not found
4236 INFO: Excluded import 'PyQt4' not found
4236 INFO: Processing hook   hook-httplib.py
4236 INFO: Processing hook   hook-encodings.py
4756 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PIL.Image.py
5318 INFO: Processing hook   hook-pywintypes.py
5488 INFO: Processing hook   hook-xml.sax.py
5488 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py
5488 INFO: Excluding import 'FixTk'
5488 WARNING:   Removing import 'FixTk'

5488 INFO: Excluding import 'Tkinter'
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem after (pip) installing Pillow. My build worked fine until then. I've solved the build problem by including both 'import FixTk' in my Python program, and 'hiddenimports=['FixTk']' in my spec file.

The other alternatives is to add an 'excludes=['PIL']' to Analysis in your spec file. However, you'll need to be aware if any future changes to your program/app might cause PIL (Pillow) to be included.